# Express/Node: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I am not sure if I am blind, but I cannot see where I am trying to send a response twice.
I am getting the error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

And it seems to be coming form the response sent in the `transporter.sendMail()` function.

My code:

```
router.route('/email').post(function(req, res) {
    var dir = req.body.moduleCode
        + '/'
        + req.body.year
        + '/'
        + req.body.semester
        + '/'
        + req.body.assignCode
        + '/';

    for ( i in req.body.documentsNoExt) {
        Student.findById(req.body.documentsNoExt[i], function (err, student) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            var mailOptions = {
                from : '"Feedbacker" <FeedbackerWebApp@gmail.com>',
                to: student.email,
                subject: 'Mark feedback for ' + req.body.assignCode,
                text: 'Dear ' + student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName + ','
                + 'Please find attached your feedback for the assignment ' + req.body.assignCode + ' module ' + req.body.moduleCode + '.',
                attachments: [
                    {
                        path: './server/pdfs/' + dir + student._id + '.pdf',
                    }
                ]
            }
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Successfully sent emails!' });
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Here is my http post in angular2:

```
sendEmail(documents, assignment) {
        this.progress = 1;
        var documentsNoExt = documents.map(function (e) {
            return e.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
        });
        var emailInfo = {
            "moduleCode"    : assignment.modInsID[0].modID[0]._id,
            "year"          : assignment.modInsID[0].year,
            "semester"      : assignment.modInsID[0].semester,
            "assignCode"    : assignment.code,
            "documentsNoExt": documentsNoExt
        };
        this.authHttp.post("/api/email", JSON.stringify(emailInfo), this.options).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.sendInfoMsg("Succesfully sent E-mails.", "success");
                this.progress = 2;
            },
            err => this.sendInfoMsg(err._body, "danger")
        );
    }
```

any idea where I have sent a response twice as I cannot see what is causing it.

Comment: oh shoot! Is it because the transporter.sendMail is in a loop! aha... *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

You are sending multiple responses in your loop that's why you are getting this error.

> Instead of `res.send()` you should use `res.write()` to send multiple responses.

---

> `res.send()` sends entire `HTTP` response to the client includes `headers` and `content` even it `ends the response`.
>   And after that, you can't send anything.